# How to check whether a file is present or not in the internal file system of android

Tags: android, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786655/test-if-file-exists)

I have stored one file in /files folder of my android app internal file system. I want to check whether it is stored there or not programatically.How i can check that?Please help me.

```
File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("Android.mk"); if(file.exists()) { Toast.makeText(this,"Android.mk exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look on this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786655/test-if-file-exists

Comment: file.exists() is the way to go

Comment: File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("Android.mk");
  if(file.exists())
  {
   Toast.makeText(this,"Android.mk exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 
  }

Comment: I have tried that and i have stored that file by creating the files folder in the android app itself.Not on the sd card or somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I write a file in the internal storage like described in the Android dev-tut ([Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)) to my applications private storage, Iam able to verify with you code that the file has been written successfully!

So the verification code should be all right. Maybe the way you are writing the file is wrong. Here is my code snippet:

```
String FILENAME = "Android.mk";
String string = "hello world";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, getBaseContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();

File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("Android.mk");
if (file.exists()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Android.mk exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```