# Android; Check if file exists without creating a new one

Tags: android, file, file-io

I want to check if file exists in my package folder, but I don't want to create a new one.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
if(file.exists()) 
     return true;
```

Does this code check without creating a new file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if file exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786655/test-if-file-exists)

Comment: @Kunok I'm checking your edit comment: *removed words such as **tanks** as they are...* :P

Comment: @KevinGuan Oh yeah my bad, just got home from new eve party so I was not able to write properly :)

Answer (score 490, accepted):

Your chunk of code does not create a new one, it only checks if its already there and nothing else.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
if(file.exists())      
//Do something
else
// Do something else.
```

Comment: Dont know why in my case this code is creating a new file.

Comment: How to check in sub folder also?

Comment: This is like that because there is no static method : File.exists(String file) , so you have to instanciate a new File object to access 'Exists' method.

Comment: I think OP doesn't wish to create new file object.

Comment: @AndroDev no - he doesn't wish to create new FILE, answer creates new REFERENCE to file.

Comment: [AmirGolan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11878751/amir-golan) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62218537/3744182): *when you give the file path, don't forget to include file name at the end of the path. It sounds stupid, but it took me two days to notice I forgot it.*

Answer (score 34):

When you use this code, you are not creating a new File, it's just creating an object reference for that file and testing if it exists or not.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
if(file.exists()) 
    //do something
```

Answer (score 30):

It worked for me:

```
File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),"whatever.txt");
if(file.exists()){
   //Do something
}
else{
   //Do something else
}
```

Comment: This is the solution if you only have the file name and not its path

Comment: @Zach Not really, it's path would be the first parameter I sent ( getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() )

Answer (score 10):

When you say "in you package folder," do you mean your local app files? If so you can get a list of them using the [Context.fileList()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#fileList%28%29) method. Just iterate through and look for your file. That's assuming you saved the original file with [Context.openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Sample code (in an Activity):

```
public void onCreate(...) {
    super.onCreate(...);
    String[] files = fileList();
    for (String file : files) {
        if (file.equals(myFileName)) {
            //file exits
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `methods` in the Path class are syntactic, meaning that they operate on the Path instance. But eventually you must access the `file` system to verify that a particular Path exists

```
 File file = new File("FileName");
 if(file.exists()){
 System.out.println("file is already there");
 }else{
 System.out.println("Not find file ");
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(new File("/sdcard/your_filename.txt").exists())){
              // Your code goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean FileExists(String fname) {
        File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fname);
        return file.exists();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin Extension Properties

No file will be create when you make a File object, it is only an interface.

To make working with files easier, there is an existing `.toFile` function on Uri

You can also add an extension property on File and/or Uri, to simplify usage further.

```
val File?.exists get() = this?.exists() ?: false
val Uri?.exists get() = File(this.toString).exists()
```

Then just use `uri.exists` or `file.exists` to check.