# How to find if the file exist or not in Android?

Tags: android, file, storage, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

I have write the following code to write a file-

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("MyFile",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

//Saving my list
os.writeObject(EmailStackClass.list);
os.close();
```

how can i identify if the file is already exist ? Because if the file is created previously, then i have to append my data on the previous file.
Please help me...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, have a look around before making new questions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237950/android-check-if-file-exists-without-creating-a-new-one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16238204/1665507 check it out.

Answer (score 1):

try below code :-

```
File f = new File("MyFile"); // PATH OF YOUR FILE
        if(f.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("file exist");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("file not exist");
        }
```

Comment: I am always getting file not exist

Comment: @user2166895 IT MEANS YOUR FILE NOT EXIST !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check as follows...

```
File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fileName);
if(file.exists()) {

    //do something with the existed file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Check this..

```
File file = new File("dirPath", "fileName");
if(file.exists()){
        // file exists
}else{
        // file not exists
}
```

hope this help you..

Comment: I do not know the dirPath ,

Comment: how did you created that file?

Comment: FileOutputStream fos = ctxt.openFileOutput("MyFile",
     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

os.writeObject(EmailStackClass.list);
os.close();

Comment: from where "MyFile" this file may be in SDCARD/PhoneStorage/ASSETS ??