# How to know whether a file exists or not in internal/external storage in android?

Tags: android, storage, file-search

I think this question may be a duplicate but I didn't find any other answers for this.

My question is:

Is it possible to know whether a file (e.g.: a `.txt`/`.doc`/`.csv` file) exists or not in any location (i.e. internal/external storage) in the device?

Comment: what you have try until now??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android; Check if file exists without creating a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237950/android-check-if-file-exists-without-creating-a-new-one)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java

Comment: i tried Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and Environment.getDataDirectory() both to search but these two are not searching in internal storage(Built-in Storage).

Comment: you have folder in this storage(internal or external) ??

Comment: actually my file is in internal storage Download folder..

Comment: ok so you have to check if file exist or not right??

Comment: yes i want to check a file existed or not..

Comment: in Download folder right?? and in internal storage??

Comment: thats an example actually my problem is i don't know where the file is located/path. here i know just file name itself(ex: MyTest.txt) not path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105011/discussion-between-nils-patel-and-syam-vakkalanka).

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the path of the file you can use the following code:

```
File yourFile = new File(yourFilePath);
yourFile.exists();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works in your case.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "filename with extention");
File file2 = new File("internal sotrage path here" + File.separator + "filename with extention");
try {
    if(file.exists()){
        // code if file exist in external storage
    }
    else if(file2.exists()){
        // code if file exist in internal storage
    }
    else {
        // file not found
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but here my problem is i'm failed to get Internal storage path.

Comment: actually i'm new to android don't know how to get internal storage folders. if you have idea please support me with some snippet of code..

Comment: try Environment.getDataDirectory()

Answer (score 0):

```
 Future<String?> _saveFileToDevice(String filename, List<int> data) async {
// Get the path to the app's documents directory
var status = await Permission.storage.status;
if (!status.isGranted) {
  await Permission.storage.request();
}

var dir = Platform.isAndroid
    ? '/storage/emulated/0/Download'
    : (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;

// Create the file and write the data to it
var file = File('$dir/$filename');

bool alreadyDownloaded = await file.exists();

String incrementCount(String fileName) {
  int dotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
  String newFileName = fileName.substring(0, dotIndex) +
      "(${count += 1})" +
      fileName.substring(dotIndex);

  return newFileName;
}

if (alreadyDownloaded) {
  String newFileName = incrementCount(file.path);

  var newFile = File('$newFileName');
  await newFile.writeAsBytes(data, flush: true);

  String subStringFileName = newFileName.substring(29);
  CommonWidgets.makeToast(
      fontSize: 14,
      toastMsg: '${subStringFileName} saved to Downloads Folder');

  file = newFile;
  print('modified updating ....--> $file');
} else {
  await file.writeAsBytes(data, flush: true);

  CommonWidgets.makeToast(
      fontSize: 14,
      toastMsg: '${filename} saved to Downloads Folder');
}

return 'file://${file.path}';
}
```

Data is Uint8List Bytes which can convert the file into bytes and pass the byteslist