# How to check two file exist in same folder?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to check two file exists in same folder like *music1.mp3* and *music2.mp3* in folder *Testapp*?
This my code check one file:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Testapp/music1.mp3");
if(f.exists()) { 
   /* do something */ 
} else {
   /* do something */ 
}
```

Comment: Why not simply do the same for the second file?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237950/android-check-if-file-exists-without-creating-a-new-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
File yourDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Testapp");
for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
if (f.isFile()){
    String name = f.getName();
    if(name.equals("music1.mp3")) {
    // music1.mp3 present
    } else if(name.equals("music2.mp3")) {
    // music2.mp3 present
    }
  }
}
```

More efficient way as suggested by @Henry below in comments

```
File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Testapp/music1.mp3");
File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Testapp/music2.mp3");
if (file1.exists()) {
 // music1.mp3 present
} else if (file2.exists()) {
 // music2.mp3 present
}
```

Comment: What a complicated solution!

Comment: Worst possible solution for this.

Comment: A bit better, but still, it is not necessary to do a directory list and compare file names when you can test for existence directly.

Comment: @Henry thanks a lot for the info, i have updated the answer as per suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by checking the **both files parent path**

```
File f1 = new File("pathone");
File f2 = new File("pathtwo");
if (f1.exists()&&f2.exists()) {
   if (f1.getParent().equals(f2.getParent())) { 
      //both in same folder
   } else {
      //diff folder
   }
}
```